# Tailing Kubernetes job logs that fail

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following project:

```
database-migration/
    migration.yml
    kustomization.yml
```

Where `kustomization.yml` looks like:

```
resources:
  - migration.yml
images:
  - name: enterprise-server
    newTag: 2020.12-6243
    newName: example/enterprise-server
configMapGenerator:
  - name: database-config
    literals:
      - ADMIN_REPOSITORY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.34:5432/app_db
      - AGENT_REPOSITORY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.34:5432/app_db
      - DB_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT=60000
      - DB_CONNECTION_MAX_LIFETIME_TIMEOUT=120000
secretGenerator:
  - name: database-credentials
    literals:
      - ADMIN_REPOSITORY_USERNAME=app_admin
      - ADMIN_REPOSITORY_CONNECTION_USERNAME=app_admin@10.1.0.34
      - ADMIN_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD=12345
      - AGENT_REPOSITORY_USERNAME=app_agent
      - AGENT_REPOSITORY_CONNECTION_USERNAME=app_agent@10.1.0.34
      - AGENT_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD=23456
commonLabels:
  app.kubernetes.io/version: 2020.12-6243
  app.kubernetes.io/part-of: myapp
```

And where `migration.yml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: database-migration
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: database-migration
    app.kubernetes.io/component: database-migration
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: database-migration
        app.kubernetes.io/component: database-migration
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: database-migration
          image: enterprise-server
          env:
            - name: CLOUD_ENVIRONMENT
              value: KUBERNETES
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: database-config
            - secretRef:
                name: database-credentials
          command: ['sh', '-c', '/usr/local/app_enterprise/bin/databaseMigration || [ $? -eq 15 ]; exit $?']
      restartPolicy: Never
```

When I run:

```
kubectl create ns appdb
kubectl -n appdb apply -k database-migration
kubectl -n appdb wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=10m job/database-migration
```

It just hangs for 10 minutes and then fails:

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition on jobs/database-migration
```

I'd like to tail logs or just look at logs (even after the fact) but not sure how to get logs for a job that has failed, or how to tail logs for an ongoing job. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Job creates pods for execution. You can just check the pods (or all elements)

`kubectl -n appdb get all`

and then request the logs for the pod, for example

`kubectl -n appdb logs -f database-migration-xyz123`

Answer (score 1):

### Few notes about `Kustomization`

- If you are using `Kustomization` you can use it for the creation of the `Namesapce` as well obviously.
- Add the namespace to your `kustomization.yaml` file so it will be added to all of your resources

---

> I'd like to tail logs or just look at logs

In order to view or tail your logs:

```sh
# get the name of your Job Pod and get the logs
kubectl logs -n <namespace> jox-xxxxx

# To tail your logs (follow)
kubectl logs -n <namespace> -f jox-xxxxx
```

#### How to get logs of "crashed" jobs?

- Add the `--previous` flag

```sh
# Add the `--previous` flag to your logs command
kubectl logs -n <namespace> jox-xxxxx --previous
```

---

#### Logs output example

[image]